# Counting all order items for ecommerce site

Tags: python, django, model, one-to-many, counter

I'm building a food delivery website.  I currently have it all set up, but i am building the admin page that aggregates the total amount of orders for each type of food.

The "location"  attribute has 6 possible drop off points. and i have 3 delivery drop off times. I want to count all the individual food items for each delivery time/location.  I'm not sure how to do this using django.

what would be the best way to do this?

I seperated the actual "order" model from the "orderitems" models.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    # each individual status 
    SUBMITTED = 1
    PROCESSED = 2
    SHIPPED = 3
    CANCELLED = 4

    # set of possible order statuses 
    ORDER_STATUSES = ((SUBMITTED,'Submitted'), (PROCESSED,'Processed'),
                        (SHIPPED,'Shipped'), (CANCELLED,'Cancelled'),)

    # order info
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=ORDER_STATUSES, default=SUBMITTED)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)


    #user info
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    # contact info
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50) 
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    # Drop point info
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    #time of the drop info
    time = models.IntegerField()

    # billing information
    billing_name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    billing_address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    billing_address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True) 
    billing_city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    billing_state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    billing_country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    billing_zip = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Order #' + str(self.id)
```

Orderitem:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Food)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [annotate and Count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses):

```
orders = orders.annotate(num_items=Count('orderitem_set'))

for order in orders:
    print order.pk, order.num_items
```